# Medieval fantasy movie where a sorceress disguises herself as the queen to have a child by the king

Tags: story-identification, movie

This was a 1980s(?) medieval fantasy movie where there is a sorceress who puts a spell on a king so he thinks he is having sex with his love but it is actually her?

She has a child in secret who she then dresses in gold armor and sprinkles with gold magic dust so he cannot be killed.

Later she loses her powers to keep herself looking young, becomes instantly old and he is disgusted by the sight of her and kills her.

Comment: Hmm. This is quite similar to the plot of *[Savage Sword of Conan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savage_Sword_of_Conan)*

Comment: This was also a key plotline in the 2011 TV show *Camelot*. Morgan tricks Arthur into having sex with her by impersonating the queen.

Comment: @Valorum It also reminded me of the "movie" _[Merlin (1998)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merlin_(miniseries))_ which had a similar plot too. I think that was the first time I saw Sam Neil and Helena Bonham Carter.

Comment: This is a standard part of Arthurian myth, so could be many things

Answer (score 53):

You might be remembering [*Excalibur*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excalibur_(film)) (1981).

In *Excalibur*, there are actually two instances of someone magically taking the form of another's partner for the purpose of sexual relations. The first instance takes place near the beginning, when Merlin uses magic to transform Uther Pendragon's appearance into that of the Duke of Cornwall in order to seduce Igrayne, the duke's wife. The product of that union is Arthur.

But in that first case, the genders are reversed from what you described, so you must be remembering the second instance from later in the film, in which Morgana (Arthur's half-sister) takes on the form of Guinevere for the purpose of mating with Arthur, the result of which is Mordred.

Morgana does indeed bestow Mordred with a golden set of armor.

[image]

And sprinkles him with gold dust.

[image]

Late in the film, Mordred does kill his mother Morgana in disgust, after her true aged self is revealed as a result of Merlin tricking her into speaking the Charm of Making, which expends all of her magical power.

Comment: Yes!! It is Excalibur from 1981!!! Thank you so much! I love that film! I’m going to now watch it again. 